Как параллельно запустить 2 асинхронные функции?
Помогите ответом. Не могу найти ответа, как параллельно запускать асинхронные функции в Python?
Пример кода:
async def func1():
    print('Текст 1')
    # await asyncio.sleep(5)
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Текст 2')

async def func2():
    print('Текст 3')

async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(func1())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(func2())
    await t1
    await t2

asyncio.run(main())

Результат должен быть таким:
Текст 1
Текст 3
Текст 2

т.е. "func1" выводит "Текст 1", потом пока "func1" отдыхает "func2" выводит "Текст 3", а после "func1" выводит "Текст 2"
С НЕ асинхронными функциями через "threading" проблема решается, но перевести их в НЕ асинхронные функции нет возможности потому как в них используются асинхронные методы.

'Не могу найти ответа" А вы точно пытались искать?

Берём заголовок, вставляем в гyгл, переходим по второй же ссылке...

Сергей, благодарю вас за ответ. Очень информативный, а главное полезный. Вы не поверите. Я не сторонник без необходимости задавать вопросы на всевозможных форумах. К сожалению гугл тут не помог. Аналогичных заголовков выдает хулиард, но все без результата.

А теперь, чтобы асинхронные функции работали асинхронно, то они должны быть собственно асинхронными, а вы зачем-то воткнули абсолютно синхронный time.sleep, который естественно блокирует всё и всех

andreymal, заходил я по этой ссылке. Сейчас я поправил код исход из того решения, которое там было предложено. Не работает.

Когда вы сделаете свои функции асинхронными — заработает

andreymal, спасибо. Не знал, что синхронные методы ИМЕННО блокируют выполнение асинхронных функций.  Думал, что раз нет ошибок то все норм и проблема не в этом. Отсюда и не мог решить простую задачу. Раскомментировал асинхронный слип и все норм.

andreymal, Что Вы подразумеваете "сделаете свои функции асинхронными" - т.е. что бы все методы в них были исключительно асинхронными?

Как минимум чтобы в них был await, и чтобы они не содержали в себе слишком долгий синхронный код (по умолчанию питон считает, что «слишком долгий» это 100мс и дольше, но чем быстрее тем конечно лучше). Чтобы event loop мог приступить к выполнению других асинхронных функций, текущая выполняемая функция должна передать управление программой в этот самый event loop — а это происходит только в await. Тот же синхронный time.sleep не имеет await, он просто блокирует собой текущий поток, управление не передаётся в event loop и в итоге ничего не происходит

@ИванМаксимович если в асинхронном коде вызываются синхронные блокирующие функции, можно разве что обернуть их в await asyncio.to_thread() (т.е. вызывать в отдельных потоках). По коду - параллельно ожидать два awaitable объекта нужно через asyncio.gather или asyncio.wait (если не нужно собирать результаты в список)

insolor, принял спасибо!
